# Can we build a Xamarin based android system application in visual studio or Android studio IDE?

Tags: xamarin.forms

I want build and debug a xamarin based "SYSTEM" android application in visual studio. Is it doable?

Comment: You have to use Visual Studio to build Xamarin apps.  What else would you use?

Comment: Sorry I meant xamarin based system application

Comment: I think the only difference between a system app and any other app is the location its installed.

Comment: I don't think so as we need to root the device and create application with different permissions to get the system level access

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is doable, therefore you need this:

- Xamarin.Android 7.5 or later
- Android Studio 3.x with Java 1.8

More information how to set up the system you can find [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/tools/dotnet-embedding/get-started/java/android).

Comment: Sorry may be I was not much clear. I meant SYSTEM apps not user apps

Answer (score 0):

[Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/deploy-test/install-system-app) is some basic information from MSDN that you can start with for distributing your Xamarin.Android app as a System app.

It's difficult to provide specifics on this topic because the way you go about doing this can shift dramatically depending on your setup. Even MSDN states that. The article provided though is a great starting point to begin to understand how to go about installing your app as a system app.